# SWT. Affine Transform. Умное масштабирование.

Tags: java, swt

Я хотел бы масштабировать (плавно увеличивать) объект (квадрат), при этом не изменяя его позиции. Есть пример кода? Как это сделать? 
Придумал частный случай. 
Код, рисующий квадрат:

```
@Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        final GC gc = e.gc;
        gc.setAdvanced(true);
        gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);

        gc.setTransform(transform);
        gc.setBackground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
        gc.fillRectangle(rect);

    }
```

Код, изменяющий экземпляр объекта Transform: 
    /*
         ** Коэффициент, изменяющий коэффициент масштабирования (m11) и коэффициент позиционирования (dx)*
         /
        private static final float COEF = 1.0f; 
    //переменные класса
    private float m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy;

```
//код метода handleEvent
//получить объект
final Transform transform = ...getTransform();
        final float[] array = new float[6];
//заполнить массив значениями коэффициентов матрицы трансформации
        transform.getElements(array);
        if (m11 == 0) {
            m11 = array[0];
            //m12 = array[1];
            //m21 = array[2];
            m22 = array[3];
            dx = array[4];
            //dy = array[5];

        }

        if(m11> COEF){
            dx = -100 * (m11- COEF);            
        }

        transform.setElements(m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy);

        m11 += COEF;

// redraw object
```

Как изменить алгоритм, чтобы он работал при коэффициенте (**COEF**) **0.1f** и **0.01f**?

---

К моему сожалению, качество ответов оставляет желать лучшего. 
Вот как надо было ответить. Коротко, а не вобщем.

---

```
/**
     * Коэффициент изменяющий коэффициент масштабирования (m11) и коэффициент позиционирования (dx)
     */
    private static final float COEF = 0.01f;    
    private float m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy;

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        if (event.type != SWT.MouseUp) {
            return;
        }

        final Transform transform = ContainerPaintListener.getTransform();
        final float[] array = new float[6];
        transform.getElements(array);
        if (m11 == 0) {
            m11 = array[0];
//          m12 = array[1];
//          m21 = array[2];
            m22 = array[3];
            dx = array[4];
//          dy = array[5];

        }

        //"100" - это исходная ширина квадрата  
        if(m11>1){
            dx -= 100*COEF;         
        }

        transform.setElements(m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy);

        m11 += COEF;
```

Answer (score 2):

*Заполняя матрицу руками, вы просто переизобрели велосипед.*

Отрисовывайте все с помощью матриц трансформации (которые в `swt.graphics` неявно используются в `Transform`).

*Конкретно в вашем случае скейлинг квадрата происходит относительно его центра, что можно описать следующим набором аффинных преобразований:*

**Считаем, что изначально квадрат расположен верхним левым углом в `(X, Y)`, нижним правым - в `(X + T, Y + T)`.**

1. Необходимо перевести систему координат в центр квадрата, т.е в точку `(X + T/2, Y + T/2)`. Делается это при помощи `transform.translate(X + T/2, Y + T/2);`
2. Далее мы "растягиваем" координатные оси, совершая масштабирования квадрата относительно его центра: `transform.scale(k, k)`, `k` - коэффициент масштабирования.

---

Поскольку матрицы в объекте `Transform` перемножаются, то вам достаточно вызвать `translate` и `scale` последовательно, чтобы получить финальное преобразование системы отсчета. Дальше уже, собственно, можно выполнять отрисовку.